# Where can I find the application route and id for Bluemix iOS 8 mobile app?

Tags: ios, node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm starting my first BlueMix app (Node.js + iOS 8). From the dashboard, can anyone explain how I locate the application id, and application route?  A tutorial I'm following indicates there should be a "Mobile Options" button that will show this level of detail, but I've had no luck locating this button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Mobile Options" link would be in the Overview of your app in the upper right corner (right next to the 'Add Git' link).  But, you'll only find this for apps using the Mobile Application Security service (for iOS 7 or lower).

For iOS 8 apps, the Advanced Mobile Access service is used from the catalog.  To see the route and UID, you can select the Mobile Application Service from the 'Services' section of the left navigation.  Then you'll see this information in the 'Common Client Information' panel on the right.

Before proceeding too much further, you might want to take a look at a tutorial specifically targeting iOS 8 - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-mfp-ios8-app/index.html